# how to replace in string using regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, replace

I have below as string

```
name : abc,
position : 2
```

I want to make replace so that the string becomes as below

```
name : "abc",
position : 2
```

What change I want to do is abc will have double quotes so `abc` becomes `"abc"`.

Note: abc is dynamic, it can be anything as below.

```
name : Test,
position : 2

name : Great,
position : 2

name : developers,
position : 2
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Your requirements are not that clear. Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/jxfo3B) for Case 1. With the second case, isn't it a simple string replacement candidate?

Comment: explain a bit  `Anything can be anything?`

Comment: okay, then what are `great, test, developers` here they must be an object?

Comment: @vaibhav : no, its a string...

Comment: So, there is no need to remove the comma now?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Fa3KTC

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Perfect... Can you post this as an answer? I will accept it right away... Thanks a ton...

Comment: @vaibhav : check answer... that is what I was looking for....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `\\b(name\\s*:\\s*)(.+),` pattern and replace with `$1"$2",`:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myText = @"name : abc,\nposition : 2";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b(name\\s*:\\s*)(.+)," options:nil error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length]) withTemplate:@"$1\"$2\","];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

See the [Objective-C demo](https://ideone.com/Fa3KTC)

**Details**:

- `\\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(name\\s*:\\s*)`  - Group 1 matching `name`, 0+ whitespaces, `:` and 0+ whitespaces again
- `(.+)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `,` - comma

The replacement pattern - `$1"$2",` - inserts Group 1 contents, `"`, Group 2 contents and `",`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dYdzpm/2).

Comment: Its not working for first name if string is `\t\tThis is test \t\tname : abc,\nposition : 2\n\nname : xyz,\nposition : 3\n\nname : jkl,\nposition : 3`. Can you please look into this?

Comment: Replace `(?m)^` with `\\b`

Comment: Perfect... Will let you know if there is anything else... Thanks a Ton!!!

Comment: `\\b(name\\s*:\\s*)([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*,` should work more better. Right? Here: [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dYdzpm/3)

Comment: Just suit yourself, only you know the exact type of data coming in. If there can only be ASCII letters after `name:` and there may be optional whitespaces before a `,`, yes, it will be better. `.+` just matches the whole rest of the line. You might also want to check if `\\b(name\\s*:\\s*)(.*\\S)\\s*,` works "better" if there can be literally anything (but at least 1 non-whitespace) up to optional whitespace and `,`. Mind that `\s` matches a newline, so, if you want to stay within 1 line, replace `\\s` with `[\\p{Zs}\t]` or `[^\\S\r\n]`.